# Ошибка приведения типов при использовании ExecuteScalar

Tags: c#

Ошибка в синтаксе как исправить. Пытаюсь сделать проверку на существования этого hwid в базе данных. Но проблема синтаксиса вылазит как исправить ?

```
        string connStr = $"server=sql2***hosting.eu;user=u983222****;database=u9832***;password=t***;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();

        DateTime d1;
        try
        {
            string sql = $"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myusers WHERE hwid = '{hwid}'";

            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                int userCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
                if (userCount > 0)
                {
                    button2.Text = "Лицензия активна";
                    status = true;
                    this.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    button2.Text = "Лицензия не найдена";
                    status = false;
                }


            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            button2.Text = "Не удалось подключиться";

        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Mike  спасибо, теперь вылетела след. ошибка

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov 
Ошибка CS0030 Не удается преобразовать тип "System.Type" в "int"

Comment: сделал так и все заработало var userCount = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

Comment: @Alexander Petrov System.Type

Comment: Каким образом я верну, там скрины были залиты их у меня нету уже.

Comment: @СерегаWend На самом деле все можно вернуть (пишу исключительно, что бы знали чуть больше об интерфейсе SO). Если нажать под вопросом на "Изменен X часов назад", то увидите историю правок и там ваши скрины старые есть и достаточно на старой версии нажать "откатить" и она станет текущей. *НО* делать этого, конечно, не нужно. Предыдущий вопрос можно было смело удалять или закрывать по "вызван опечаткой". В текущей редакции, тем более с ответом, он очень даже ничего. Особенно если заголовок поправить и убрать из него про sql.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov В предыдущей редакции вопроса он был вызван опечаткой, значит ему было не место на SO. Сейчас он описывает вполне определенную ошибку, которая встречается в практике (есть такой же на английском SO) и содержит ответ по существу. И даже если сам факт его изменения был не корректен, итоговый результат стал приемлемым. Откат не требуется

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494353/cast-to-int-on-sqlcommand-executescalar-error-handling

Answer (score 0):

Заменили эту строку:

int userCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

на

var userCount = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

---

```
        var userCount = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
            if (userCount > 0)
            {
                button2.Text = "Лицензия активна";
                status = true;
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                button2.Text = "Лицензия не найдена";
                status = false;
            }
```